# Unknown jQuery variable in Firefox web-console

Tags: jquery, firefox, web-console

Accessing jQuery variable in Firefox web-console I see (form the autocomplete) a second jQuery variable;
the variable looks like `jQuery85448957324..` ('jQuery' followed by a random number).

Initially accessing this variable  gave a result that refered to ...`toJSON: .noop()`...,
but now it's returning ReferenceError:

```
jQueryxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is not defined
```

what does this variable refer to?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong that breaks jQuery and maby jQuery UI too.

1. Are you using AJAX? Try to check if your response is a valid JSON...
2. Are you using JSONP? Maby the callback throws that error...
3. Are you using a custom itemRender? Make sure to have a valid ui.item...

Debug your items using a UI Autocomplete callback like:

```
selected: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.item);
}
```

API: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: it's an integrated bootstrap-wp environment (so there are several jquery plugins from the bootstrap & wordpress framework): I've notice that looking at the site from another firefox browser therandom number has changed ,the variable responds Object { toJSON: .noop(), events: Object, handle: n.event.add/r.handle() },

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle, otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: it's related to firefox web-console , I've added an img that's showing the output;

Comment: Does not help, like I said... provide a jsfiddle or debug your code like I mention in the 1 to 3 steps